# SignalR in Layout and partial page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to use a SignalR hub in a layout and in a partial page. [Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1884408/5309678.aspx/1?using%20connection%20hub%20start%20done%20at%20multiple%20places%20in%20application) it is described to use `hub.start` and `done` functions.

So I have two script blocks in my html page where i want to use SignalR:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();
        window.hubReady.done(function () {
            ...
        });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        window.hubReady.done(function() {
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the second script block it says that `windows.hubReady.done` can't be executed because it's undefined.

EDIT: block 2 is executed before block 1. But why?

Comment: Are the two ready functions in the same order as you posted them?

Comment: yes they are in the same order

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the second callback is executed before the first, and if that's the case then window.hubReady is null since it's the first callback that initializes window.hubReady.

I would suggest that you don't create a global reference to your hub and instead reference it directly, ie:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.connection.hub.connected(function() {
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

(If this doesn't work then I suspect your hub named "hub" isn't defined on the server, but that's a different issue)

Comment: the second callback is executed before the first. So line 1100 is executed before line 76. I don't understand why.

Comment: i think your guess is that  the second callback is executed _BEFORE_ the first?

Comment: The lines are executed in order, however, the functions aren't necessarily executed in the order of the document since they are callbacks. It's jQuery that decides the order of execution.

Comment: So i don't know the order what is bad. Is there something in SignalR to test if the hub is already started?

Comment: ok, new question on this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066693/signalr-check-if-hub-already-started

Comment: Check the documentation, there are event's you can hook up directly to you hub

Comment: can you be more explicit? connected is not a function by the way

Comment: You can attach events with standard jQuery-syntax: .bind("onStart", function(e) {});

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by not calling `$(document).ready(function(e)` but  `$(window).load(function()` in my partial html.    `$(window).load(function()` is called second then.

Comment: Just a warning: it's not very reliable, it may break in the future if something changes, ex. jQuery-internals, the order of your scripts etc.